# Zend 1.11. headScript()->captureStart() content should be included last

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, zend-framework

we are working on a Zend 1.11. based application. 
In the overall layout, we use

```
$this->inlineScript()->appendFile(...)
```

to add all required global libraries such as jQuery.

In some individual views, we need local JavaScripts we included via

```
<?php $this->inlineScript()->captureStart(); ?>
jQuery(document).ready((function() {
    alert('ping');
}));
<?php $this->inlineScript()->captureEnd(); ?>
```

Here the problem is: The layout file is processed after the view, thus the captured content is obove the library include in the inlineScript stack. As a result, in the html, we get them printed in a way that jQuery is not loaded before our view specific script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<!--
jQuery(document).ready((function() {
  alert('ping');
}));
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../js/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

We did not found any solution browsing the Zend code to let the HeadScript helper print the includes first and the inline script afterwards. Does anybody know how to get this working (first including the script references and printing inline scripts afterwards)?

Thanks a lot
Ben

Comment: By the way: we currently use headScript() for the file includes and inlineScript() for the captured javascripts. However, as the documentation says, headScript() should be used to print the content in the head. So we would prefer to have a more consistent solution using inlineScript() only.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the problem. The inline script content will be output wherever in the layout you echo the inline script helper. What's stopping you putting this call just before the `</body>` in the layout?

Comment: Load jquery from a bootstrap might help you to solve this problem : http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.view.placeholders.standard.html

Comment: @Tim: Nothing. This is what we are doning at the moment. However, we thought it might be possible or more clearer to use one type of script object (head or inline) and teach him to treat inline and linked files differently.

Answer (score 1):

Aha, I should have checked the first code sample a bit more closely. In your layout you have:

```
$this->inlineScript()->appendFile(...)
```

you then said you wanted a solution to "let the HeadScript helper print the includes first and the inline script afterwards". But you aren't using the head script helper at the moment (at least none of the code in your question is).

The call in your layout should be:

```
$this->headScript()->appendFile(...)
```

and you will need a corresponding call to echo the result of the head script helper (within the `<head>...</head>` part of your layout). There are [several examples in the documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headscript) if you need to see how this should look.

Then you can leave the rest of your inline script calls as-is, and it shoudl all work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is very old, but since i did not find any answer here or elswhere, i wanted to share my solution to the problem, it may maybe help someone else having the exact same problem.

Was looking for a answer myself
We are using ZendX_JQuery View Helpers (ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper_JQuery) to include jquery ($this->jQuery() on layout)

it has some nice functions to add JS-Files, but also scripts to the HEAD after the jquery was included, no mather if calling those after or before che inclusion of the jquery js-file itself.

Resolution of your specific problem would be:

```
<?php
    $this->jQuery()->javascriptCaptureStart();

    echo <<<JS
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert('ping');
        });
    JS;

    $this->jQuery()->javascriptCaptureEnd();
```